# Gridview Sort using Linq query datasource

Tags: sorting, gridview

I'm trying to sort a grid view by the columns State and DateandTime. I'm not setting the gridView's DataSourceID property so I'm tracking the sortexpression and sort direction with ViewState variables. The state and direction are correct in DatabindgOrgEventListing, but the gridview does not display sorted.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uplOrgEventListing" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="grdOrgEventListing" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            CssClass="gridorgeventlisting" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="gridorgeventlistingaltrow" AllowSorting="true"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdOrgEventListing_SelectedIndexChanged" OnSorting="grdOrgEventListing_Sorting">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="College Fair Name">
                    <ItemStyle Width="375px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City">
                    <ItemStyle Width="135px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" SortExpression="State">
                    <ItemStyle Width="35px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="DateAndTime" HeaderText="Date &amp; Time" SortExpression="DateAndTime">
                    <ItemStyle Width="290px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlState" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>



    private string GetSortDirection(string column)
    {
        string sortDirection = "DESC";
        string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

        if (sortExpression != null)
        {
            if (sortExpression == column)
            {
                string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
                if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "DESC"))
                {
                    sortDirection = "ASC";
                }
            }

        }
        else
            sortDirection = "ASC";

        ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
        ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;

        return sortDirection;
    }

    protected void grdOrgEventListing_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
        DatabindgOrgEventListing();
     }




   private void DatabindgOrgEventListing()
    {
        List<OrgEvent> orgEvents;
        List<OrgEventListing> orgEvents2;

        using (TlMainEntities context = new TlMainEntities())
        {
            context.States.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
            context.OrgEvents.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;

            if (ddlState.SelectedIndex > 0)
                orgEvents = OrgEventsByStateQuery(
                    context, Convert.ToInt32(ddlState.SelectedValue), DateTime.Now).ToList();
            else
                orgEvents = OrgEventsQuery(context, DateTime.Now).ToList();
        }

        string sortDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
        string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

        orgEvents2 =
                (from orge in orgEvents
                 select new OrgEventListing
                 {
                     Id = orge.Id,
                     City = orge.City,
                     State = TlMainUtilities.StateSelectCode(orge.StateId),
                     Name = orge.Name,
                     DateAndTime = (
                        orge.StartDate != null ?
                        ((DateTime)orge.StartDate).ToString("ddd, MMM dd, yyyy") + " " +
                        ((DateTime)orge.StartDate).ToString("h:mmtt").ToLower() + " - " + (
                            orge.EndDate != null ?
                            ((DateTime)orge.EndDate).ToString("h:mmtt").ToLower() :
                            String.Empty
                        ) :
                        String.Empty
                     )
                 }).ToList();
        if (sortExpression == "State")
        {
            if (sortDirection == "ASC")
                orgEvents2.OrderBy(x => x.State).ToList();
            else
                orgEvents2.OrderByDescending(x => x.State).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            if (sortDirection == "ASC")
                orgEvents2.OrderBy(x => x.DateAndTime);
            else
                orgEvents2.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateAndTime);
        }
        //orgEvents2.Sort();
        grdOrgEventListing.DataSource = orgEvents2;

        grdOrgEventListing.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following code

```
        if (sortExpression == "State")
    {
        if (sortDirection == "ASC")
            orgEvents2.OrderBy(x => x.State).ToList();
        else
            orgEvents2.OrderByDescending(x => x.State).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        if (sortDirection == "ASC")
            orgEvents2.OrderBy(x => x.DateAndTime);
        else
            orgEvents2.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateAndTime);
```

To this

```
            if (sortExpression == "State")
        {
            if (sortDirection == "ASC")
                orgEvents2 = orgEvents2.OrderBy(OrgEventListing => OrgEventListing.State).ToList();
            else
            {
                orgEvents2 = orgEvents2.OrderByDescending(OrgEventListing => OrgEventListing.State).ToList();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (sortDirection == "ASC")
                orgEvents2 = orgEvents2.OrderBy(OrgEventListing => OrgEventListing.DateAndTime).ToList();
            else
                orgEvents2 = orgEvents2.OrderByDescending(OrgEventListing => OrgEventListing.DateAndTime).ToList();
        }
```